# Rails - Get Additional Fields During Facebook Omniauth Registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth-facebook

I have Facebook authentication successfully implemented using the [omniauth-facebook gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) with [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).  However, what I want to do is, after Facebook authenticates, redirect them to a form where they can specify their password (and password confirmation) before the record is created.

How can I do this?

My code is pretty standard based on the gem's documentation:

```
 class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => "Facebook") if is_navigational_format?
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
 end

  def failure
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.username = auth.info.name.downcase.gsub(" ", "")     
  end
end
```

Comment: well, that's the whole purpose of omniauth, user don't have to remember password..just curious, why would you want that?

Comment: true.  actually, i want other fields, also.  such as their country.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding it correctly, you need the user to fill up a `profile` page before navigating through the app..something like the following should help..

in your `application_controller.rb`,

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  resource.profile_complete? ? root_path : user_profile_path(resource)
end
```

[`Devise Wiki`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in)